# SQL Server 2012: how to update parts of a string

Tags: string, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a small request, there are 2 tables that store non secure urls, example:

```
https://www.company.com/data/product.asp?pid=362
```

I need to update the value `http` to be `https`

Can someone show me how can that be done in an UPDATE statement?

```
update table product
set url = 'https'
```

I need to update all the records in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update [mytable]
set replace(substr([field],1,4)) = 'https'
where substr(field],1,4) = 'http';
```

Change this to fit your DBMS as needed.

Comment: Is this  syntax for sql server?

Comment: This code should be standard for most types of database management systems. For SQL Server 2012, you may need to change substr() to subtring()

Comment: Try
Update
[dbo].[z.ProductTypes]
SET
ImageURL = CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ImageURL,1,4), 'http', 'https'),SUBSTR('ImageURL,5,HowLongYourFieldIs);
WHERE SUBSTRING(ImageURL,1,4) = 'http;

What this does it it will concatenate the replacement substring of your first 4 characters + the substring of all the characters after your http, you just need to input how many characters you want it to do in the last substring. The only issue you may have is if any of your URLS are maxed out in your table. Because your adding an additional character you may get truncation issues.